# Set names of cells equal to value of adjacent cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns of data: the first strings such as "name1", "name2", ..., the adjacent column has data but I would like to rename the cells in this column equal to the first column's string values. E.g.:

```
    1      2
A   name1  x
B   name2  y
```

Thus, cell A2 should attain name = "name1".

```
Sub nameCells()
  Worksheets("Output").Cells(1, "A").Name = "David" 
End Sub
```

This code will name the cell A1 = "David", but I am unable to figure out how to copy the value of a cell instead of a hardcoded "David".

Comment: @pnuts Thank you your first answer is perfect. 
I fixed the question to remove the misleading .Value (should have been .Name).

Comment: If @pnuts comment solved your problem, please consider giving an "accepted answer" tick to the answer posted by idktho (which after editing to reflect the change in the question is now saying the same thing as pnuts' comment said).  Accepting answers that have helped you gains you valuable reputation points on the site, and makes it more likely for people to answer your questions in the future.

Comment: FYI there is a built-in way to do this using the UI - http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/418-tip-fastest-way-to-create-defined-names-in-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub nameCells()
  Worksheets("Output").Cells(1, "B").Name = Worksheets("Output").Cells(1, "A").Value 
End Sub
```

Comment: I edited your answer due to changes made to the question.  If you don't approve, feel free to rollback to the original version.